# Django: model OneToOneField with User can't add default value

Tags: python, django, database-migration, one-to-one

I have an model and I want to add an OneToOneField to hold the creator of an object:
models.py

```
creator = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True,
                               default=User.objects.filter(
                                   username="antoni4040"))
```

I already have a database with items and just want the default value to be the admin user, which has the username "antoni4040". When I try to migrate without the default field it asks for a default value, so I can't get away with it. But here's what I get when running makemigrations:

```
Migrations for 'jokes_app':
  0008_joke_creator.py:
    - Add field creator to joke
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 150, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 178, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 167, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 124, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 88, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(_arg_value)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 433, in serialize
    return cls.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 318, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = cls.serialize(arg)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 517, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = cls.serialize(item)
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/Jokes_Website/django-jokes/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 540, in serialize
    "topics/migrations/#migration-serializing" % (value, get_docs_version())
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <User: antoni4040>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the queryset `User.objects.filter(username="antoni4040")`. To get a model instance, you would use `User.objects.get(username="antoni4040")`.

However, you shouldn't use a a model instance for as the default in the model field. There's no error handling if the user does not exist in the database. In fact, if `models.py` is loaded before you run the initial migrations, then the `User` table won't even exist so the query will give an error.

The logic to set the default user should go in the view (or Django admin) instead of the models file.

In the admin, you could define a custom form that sets the initial value for the `creator` field.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username="antoni4040")
            kwargs['initial']['creator'] = user
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then use that model form in your admin.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
    ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: I just added "null = True" and deleted the default field, seems to work but now I have to manually set the admin...

Comment: I didn't elaborate before because you hadn't even said whether or not whether you are using the admin. It's harder to answer because you haven't showed much code. I've added an example now.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. You're right to a certain degree, that is useful, but you only change the admin page, the items already in don't get the creator value updated, it's just null, cause anything else causes problems with the migrations...

Comment: Oh, you want the value set when you run the migration. Try entering the id of the user (e.g. 5) when `./manage.py migrate` prompts you for a default. Or, you can create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to set the values. Once the values have been set, you can remove `null=True` and create a final migration to update you models.

Comment: This goes deeper than I thought, I'm going to accept the answer, but here's the link to a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543752/django-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to do this you can open up a shell and get the id for that User, then set the default to that.

The problem is, why would you do that? The first time you add a model it will use the default correctly. The second time you try to do that, it will fail because it's one to one, not many to one, so it will fail.